# Is there a way to select only all odd/even pages in the Preview app?

Tags: pdf, preview, big-sur, printing

Is there a way to select only all odd/even pages of a PDF document in the `Preview` app in order to print them via the "`Selected Page in Sidebar`" option?

I'm using the latest available version of the macOS Big Sur, `11.3`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual way of selecting Odd or Even pages only for printing is found in the Print dialog itself, in the "Paper Handling" section.

So Preview doesn't replicate this in the Sidebar. (Though it conceivably might be useful for other functions.)

[image]

It's worth mentioning that 'printing to PDF' from a PDF will not pass-through metadata such as annotations, bookmarks/table of contents, title/author, keywords, etc.

Comment: Note if you'd like to produce a PDF instead of printing, the odd/even option also applies when you select the "PDF" dropdown at the bottom left.

Also, the print UI in Google Chrome lets you specify custom pages or ranges of pages, so you could generate a PDF with say pages "1,3,5,7–10,12–14" etc and thus not be restricted to just odd / even without also having to manually select each page you wanted in the sidebar.